# Shockwave with particles

Tags: animation, particles, physics

Hi Im just starting blender and Im trying to make a planet explode after being hit by a laser, basically Im trying to figure out how I can get the shockwave particles to only emit out sideways from the torus instead of in every direction, I also was trying something I saw on a two planets colliding tutorial where you get one object to collide and push into the other but I don't have another planet so I was trying to use a torus but I dont think it's working. 
I'd appreciate any tips I dont really know what I'm doing,
Also I can post screenshots of stuff But I'm not sure what of.
cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a short cylinder for the emission object then turn off gravity field.

[image: Ring particle emitter]

The shorter you make the ring the flatter the plane of emission. Increase the Emission Normal value  for fast explosion then add drag to the particles so that they slow as they depart.